# Transaction in Room Database returning LiveData

Tags: android, transactions, android-sqlite, android-room

I'd like to prune a table from old records and then count the records in it.

```
@Transaction
private fun getOrdersCount(): LiveData<Int>
{
    val now = LocalDateTime.now()
    val firstOfMonth = now.withDayOfMonth(1)
    subop_pruning(firstOfMonth) // query that deletes older orders
    return subop_select_count() // query that returns the number of orders
}
```

unfortunately this query returns an error

> error: Method annotated with @Transaction must not return deferred/async return type androidx.lifecycle.LiveData. Since transactions are thread confined and Room cannot guarantee that all queries in the method implementation are performed on the same thread, only synchronous @Transaction implemented methods are allowed. If a transaction is started and a change of thread is done and waited upon then a database deadlock can occur if the additional thread attempts to perform a query. This restrictions prevents such situation from occurring.

Now, i'd like to do the sequence of operations -delete- and -select count- sequentially and in one transaction and return the LiveData from the -select count- operation. This seems to me legitimate. 
Questions:

1. Aren't the queries inside a transaction executed sequentially?
2. Why the error?
3. How to obtain the same behaviour, for example using a `MutableLiveData` and `InvalidationTracker.Observer#onInvalidated` notification if it's not possible to get LiveData from transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1 and 2 remain unanswered, anyway here how i bypassed the problem (as per point 3). Hope it helps someone:

```
fun getOrderCount(): LiveData<Int> = object : LiveData<Int>(0) {
    val observer = object : InvalidationTracker.Observer("order_table") {
        override fun onInvalidated(tables: MutableSet<String>) {
            requestOrderCount()
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        val tracker =
            MyRoomDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext).invalidationTracker;
        tracker.addObserver(observer)
        requestOrderCount()
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        val tracker =
            MyRoomDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext).invalidationTracker;
        tracker.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    private fun requestOrderCount() {
        // better to use coroutines than executors
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
            postValue(
                MyRoomDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext).OrderDao()
                    .getOrderCount_()
            )
        }
    }
}


@Transaction
private fun getOrdersCount_(): LiveData<Int>
{
    val now = LocalDateTime.now()
    val firstOfMonth = now.withDayOfMonth(1)
    subop_pruning(firstOfMonth) // query that deletes older orders
    return subop_select_count() // query that returns the number of orders
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change LiveData to MutableLiveData when using @Transaction annotation.
I know it is very late. But still, some folks out there can benefit from this.

Comment: Why? What effect this should have in your opinion?